# regex validation to include the enter key with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, regex, validation

i am using the jQuery.validationEngine i need to mod one property so that i can use it with a text area

rite now the regex is

```
"onlyNumberSp": {
                    "regex": /^[0-9\ ]+$/,
                    "alertText": "* Numbers only"
```

it allows numbers only and a space, i need to take out the space and include a return key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your regular expression to disallow spaces and allow newlines:

```
"regex": /^[0-9\n]+$/
```

Comment: exacly right  answer